Emacs blanks whilst resizing on MacOS
Even when running with emacs -Q, the entire Emacs window turns white, with even the modeline disappearing, whilst the frame (macOS window) is being resized.
Is there a workaround for this?

Sounds like a bug that should be reported

I have been playing with different Emacs builds, and this only seems to affect me on Emacs 29 (not 28). I will keep looking

This is getting weirder and weirder. The blank frame issues only happens with Emacs compiled by Nix. Compiling outside of the Nix sandbox fixes the oddities.

Well, that's a good start, so there's clearly some difference that might be causing it. Now it's up to finding out what it is. By any chance, is it something related to different versions of dependencies inside the sandbox?
